# A question on matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be $(2020)^2 ×(2020)^2$ complex matrices with A being invertible. Find the maximum number of complex numbers $\alpha$ for which the matrix $\alpha A+B$ is not invertible

I don't know even how to start. I tried 1 to 2 hour but still it is unsolved.

Comment: What have you tried? Usually it is helpful to investigate a special case first; for example the case when both $A$ and $B$ are diagonal matrices.

Comment: Hint: $\alpha A+B=(\alpha I+BA^{-1})A$.

Comment: How many eigenvalues can the matrix $A^{-1}B$ have?

Comment: Sorry,I don't know.